# Using a counter variable in Fortran without a loop

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran and used to Matlab, so I am having trouble transfer some of the logic over to Fortran. I have the following loop:

```
subroutine B
   use data_structure 
   integer :: i, j, n 
   real :: dt, dxi, dyi 

   allocate(R(n))
   dt = 0.5*CFL*dx**2
   dxi = 1/dx
   dyi = 1/dy
   n = 0

   do j = 1,jmax 
      do i = 1, imax 
         n = n+1 
         R(n) = -rho/dt*((ustar(i+1,j)-ustar(i,j))*dxi+(vstar(i,j+1)-vstar(i,j))*dyi)
         print*, R
      end do 
   end do 
end subroutine B
```

You can see that I am trying to update the vector R by manually summing values of n at each iteration. The program runs but isn't giving me the results that I anticipated. Is there an easier way to do this, perhaps with another do loop? Sorry, the logic of how to write it is messing me up. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest you take the [tour.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) In your case, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) We can only guess what is in `data_structure`. Also, include a minimal main program and state the results you are looking for. You may want to move the print* statement outside of the do loops so it only prints once when all the values of R have been set.

Comment: Also please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions so that more people see your question. You can add fortran90 to version specific questions, but this one is not specific. Note that Fortran 90 is very old and there are several more recent revisions.

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted some key information for understanding what B achieves.
However, I have estimated a minimal definition of module data_structure and subroutine pre_b which lists what would be required before B can be called.

You have also indicated that "n", the dimension of R is a local integer in subroutine B. This needs to be defined before `ALLOCATE ( R(n) )` or `ALLOCATE ( R(imax*jmax) )` can be called. I would separate n and k as a counter for R(n)

`print*, i,j,R(k)` would be a preferable temporary check of how R is being defined.

```
module data_structure
!
! these dimensions of arrays need to be provided somewhere
    integer :: imax = 100
    integer :: jmax = 100
!
! these need to be defined before calling B
    real :: CFL
    real :: rho
    real :: dx, dy
!
    real, allocatable :: ustar(:,:)
    real, allocatable :: vstar(:,:)
    real, allocatable :: R(:)

end module data_structure

subroutine pre_B
use data_structure 
!
! somewhere define inputs to subroutine B
!
   imax = 11
   jmax = 11
   allocate ( ustar(imax+1,jmax  ) )
   allocate ( vstar(imax  ,jmax+1) )
!
! get definition of ustar and vstar
   ustar = 1.0
   vstar = 1.0
!   
   cfl = 1.0
   rho = 1.0
   dx  = .01
   dy  = .01
!
! report these values before calling B
!       
end subroutine pre_B

subroutine B
use data_structure 
  integer :: i, j, n, k
  real    :: dt, dxi, dyi 

    n = imax*jmax   !  this is needed ( n is local to subroutine B )
    allocate ( R(n) )

    dt  = 0.5*CFL*dx**2
    dxi = 1/dx
    dyi = 1/dy

    k = 0
    do j = 1,jmax 
        do i = 1, imax 
            k = k+1 
            R(k) = -rho/dt*( (ustar(i+1,j)-ustar(i,j))*dxi    &
                           + (vstar(i,j+1)-vstar(i,j))*dyi )
            print*, i,j,R(k)
        end do 
    end do 

end subroutine B
```